# Why does Google Script automatically add 50 rows?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have code that is simply adding data from spreadsheet A to spreadsheet B. In a case where spreadsheet A has 21 rows of data and spreadsheet B only has 20 rows in it, my script is obviously trying to write to a row in spreadsheet B that doesn't exist. So the script apparently automatically adds 50 rows to make room for the excess data.

Is there a way to keep it from adding 50 rows, when one row would be sufficient?

This normally wouldn't bother me...but spreadsheet B has formatting in it, which automatically gets copied down 50 rows. This formatting doesn't look right when spreadsheet B is published to our website.

Here is my code. When the `rowCounterDTL` variable exceeds the number of rows that exist in spreadsheet B, 50 rows are automatically added to spreadsheet B.

```
//Cycle through each line item in the task log
for (var i = 0; i < dataTL.length; ++i) {

    //If the package type is Other
    if(dataTL[i][2] == "Other Item" && dataTL[i][4] == "Complete") {

      continue;

    } else if (dataTL[i][2] == "Other Item") {

      rowCounterDTL = rowCounterDTL + 1

      var daysOld = Math.round((todaysDate - dataTL[i][0])/1000/60/60/24);

      sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,1).setValue(dataTL[i][1]); //Add the client ID to column 1 of the DTL
      sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,2).setValue(dataTL[i][2]); //Add the package type to column 2 of the DTL
      sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,3).setValue(dataTL[i][3]); //Add the package notes to column 3 of the DTL
      sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,4).setValue(dataTL[i][4]); //Add the package priority to column 4 of the DTL
      sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,5).setValue(daysOld); //Add the age to column 5 of the DTL

        if (daysOld>20){

            sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,6).setValue("On Hold?");

        } else if(daysOld>7) {

            sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,6).setValue("Max!");

        } else if (daysOld>4){

            sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,6).setValue("High");

        } else if (daysOld>2){

            sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,6).setValue("Moderate");

        } else if (daysOld<3){

            sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,6).setValue("Low");

        }

      sheetDTL.getRange(rowCounterDTL,1,1,6).setBackgroundRGB(255, 121, 255)
    }

}
```

Comment: put some code in.  Maybe we can help you.

Comment: Do you have this line in your code somewhere? `for (var i = 0; i < dataTL.length; ++i) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you just insert an if statement to check the available rows first?

```
} else if (dataTL[i][2] == "Other Item") {
  if (rowCounterDTL == sheetDTL.getMaxRows()) {
    sheetDTL.insertRowAfter(rowCounterDTL);
  }
  rowCounterDTL = rowCounterDTL + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the line

`for (var i = 0; i < dataTL.length; ++i) {` in your code above this logic,

The problem resides in the `++i`.   What is happening is when you are calling ++i, it increments the value by 1 BEFORE the statements begin in your for loop.

Put `for (var i = 0; i < dataTL.length; i++) {` instead and you should be all set.

Putting the "++" after, means that you will increment i by one AFTER the logic is complete.

Comment: Yes, sorry I left that line out...however, I don't think I was clear. You know how in google spreadsheets you can delete the number of rows that show up in the sheet? So that for example, there could be only 20 rows that exist in the sheet all together. Well, when my script runs over those 20 rows, it automatically inserts 50 more rows, to make room for additional data. Is there a way to make it only add 1 row instead?